# Mixing Swift and Objective C: using Swift types in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have some legacy code in Objective C which I don't want to rewrite into Swift, but I want to use this code in Swift.

I've got this working fine, but it's awkward and long winded to have to convert between basic types in Swift and Objective C. For example, you have to convert from Int in Swift to Int32 to use it in Objective C.

To make this easier I'm happy to create additional overloads in my Objective C code which accept the Swift types. This seems easier than doing the conversion in every call site.

Is there a way to use Swift types in Objective C? Something like this:

```
-(void) doSomething:(Int*)theInt {
}
```

Is this possible?

Failing this, is it possible to create an implicit cast operator inbetween two types in Swift?

Any other proposed solutions?

As requested, here's a code sample of the current situation.

Here's the Objective C:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject 

+(void) somemethod:(int)param;

@end

@implementation TestClass

+(void) somemethod:(int)param {

}

@end
```

Here's an example of calling the method in Swift:

```
let swiftInt :Int = 2
TestClass.somemethod(Int32(swiftInt))
```

I would like to eliminate the need to convert to Int32 in every call site when calling from Swift.

Comment: Swift's `Int` is called `NSInteger` in Objective C. Edit: well, it's autobridges between, they're not same type though.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: @M_G I've added an example of the current situation as requested

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method signature to use NSInteger instead of int and it works fine without the need to cast it.

`+(void) somemethod:(int)param;`

changed to:

`+(void) somemethod:(NSInteger)param;`